# locking current appscreen of my application

Tags: android, locking, google-cloud-messaging

i need to lock my applications current screen when a specific push message send to phone, i try to make it as a transparent view but i cant get it please help me

Answer (score 0):

It definitely seems like [tounder.com](https://tounder.com) would be your best option. They take care of most set up, they let you send a notifications based on user names.

After setting up the [Android SDK](https://tounder.com/docs/android-sdk/)

All you have to do for log in is:
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
...

Tounder mTounder;

int REQUEST_CODE = 1;



Button logInBtn;

...

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    mTounder = new Tounder(this);

    ...

    if(alreadyLoggedIn()) {

        Intent fetchDeviceInfo = new Intent(this, FetchDeviceInfoActivity.class);

        fetchDeviceInfo.putExtra(TounderConstants.EXTRA_USER, mTounder.getUserId());

        startActivityForResult(fetchDeviceInfo, REQUEST_CODE);

    }else {

        logInBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent fetchDeviceInfo = new Intent(this, FetchDeviceInfoActivity.class);

                fetchDeviceInfo.putExtra(TounderConstants.EXTRA_USER, userName);

                startActivityForResult(fetchDeviceInfo, REQUEST_CODE);

            }

        });

    }

    ...

}



@Override

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    String result = data.getStringExtra(TounderConstants.EXTRA_STATUS);

    if(result.contains("Verified") || result.contains("Success")){

        Intent openNextWindow = new Intent(this, SendActivity.class);

        openNextWindow.putExtra("user", username)

        startActivity(openNextWindow);

    }else{

        mTounder.eraseUserId();

        mTounder.eraseRegId();

    }

}

}
```

Then to send a notification from device a to b would be:
(in oncreate in the btn click)

```
mTounder = new Tounder(this);
mTounder.sendNormalNotification("deviceb-username", "message");
```

Here is a video setting up the Android sdk : [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77hfYzZml9s)

I've worked with it before so if you have any questions just comment or post a new question with the tag **tounder.com**